# How to print a HTML footer on every page without the body overlapping?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to make the footer of my HTML to appear on every printed page without the body content overlapping the footer.

What I have is basically this:

```
<style>
    footer {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 5pt;
        height: 100pt;
    }
</style>
<div>
    content...
</div>
<footer>
    footer
</footer>
```

But when the body content is too large, it overlaps with the footer and I can't find a way around it.
I tried `@page { margin-bottom: 100pt; }`, but it pushes the footer up too, padding didn't work, `position: running` did nothing (I couldn't find whether any browser supports it).

The requisites to solve this are:

- the footer needs to appear on every page on print;
- the footer content can't overlap with the rest of the page;

Comment: what in the world is `position: running`?

Comment: Why not put `padding-bottom: 100pt;` on the content `<div>`?

Comment: @BSK that only works on the last page (the padding-bottom starts at the closing div tag), but I need the footer to appear on every page.

Comment: @dmikester1 https://www.w3.org/TR/css-gcpm-3/#running-syntax

Answer (score 0):

```css
footer {
        position: fixed;
        bottom: 5pt;
        height: 100pt;
        z-index:1000;
    }
```

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <title> Page Title </title>
  </head>
  
  <body>
  
    <div>
        content...
    </div>
    <footer>
        footer
    </footer>
  </body>
  
</html>
```

Use `z-index` to your `<footer>` so that your body part won't overlap your footer.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @bhavin-shah, but that only makes the footer appear in front of the content.

Comment: Then I think normally you would give the content div a bottom or maybe margin-bottom of 100pt so it comes right to the top of the footer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the CSS `calc()` function to calculate the appropriate height for the body by subtracting footer height from window height. With this approach, the two elements won't overlap, their positions can remain relative, and the height is automatically recalculated when resizing the window so your footer will always stay at the bottom.

```css
.content {
  overflow: auto;
  height: calc(100vh - 50px); /* window height - footer height */
  padding: 0 20px;
  background-color: gray;
}

.block {
  height: 100px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
  background-color: white;
}

footer {
  height: 50px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class='content'>
  <span>body</span>
  
  <div class='block'></div>
  <div class='block'></div>
  <div class='block'></div>
</div>

<footer>
  <span>footer</span>
</footer>
```

Comment: I tried that, but it didn't work. I don't know how many pages the document will have, and since it is for printing I can't use vh as unit. What could work is if I could do a @page { margin-bottom: 100pt; } but excluding the footer from that rule (@page *:not('footer') {... does not work)